# Perl Hash of Hashes, get lowest numeric key

Tags: perl, hash, key, hash-of-hashes

I have a hash of hashes where the first key is a string and the second key is an integer. I'm trying to get the lowest second key in the hash of hashes. Here's my hash.

```
%HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        8 => "fred",
        4 => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        5 => "george",
        1 => "jane",
        9 => "elroy",    # Key quotes needed.
    },
    simpsons => {
        99 => "homer",
        5  => "marge",
        3  => "bart",
    },
);
```

How do I get the lowest (minimum) key for the hash `simpsons`? In this case the answer would be `3`. The closest related search I could find was for a way to get the key with the highest value. But I'm trying to get the key with the lowest numeric value.

================== EDIT ============ MY ATTEMPT  ================

```
foreach my $cartoon (keys %HoH){
    if ($cartoon == "simpsons"){
        $HoH{$cartoon}{<numeric key>};   # somehow store and print lowest key
    }
}
```

I can't loop through the keys sequentially (1,2,3,4, etc.) and simply store and return the lowest key because the key (1,2,3,4, etc.) may not exist. I probably would have tried to store the keys in a separate array and get the minimum key stored in that array. That's my attempt. It's sort of a round about way of doing it. Since it's a round about way, next I would have done more Googling to see if there's an easier way (a one liner way) to do it.

Comment: You found a solution that returned the maximum value, but you couldn't modify it to return the minimum value instead? Not even attempt to modify it and post non-working code in the question?

Comment: I added my thought process and attempt of how I would have tried to solve it.

Comment: I think posting your attempt is important, even if it doesn't work (maybe _especially_ if it doesn't work), because it shows a good-faith attempt to solve your own problem and motivates other people to want to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw(min);
print min(keys(%{$HoH{simpsons}}));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $min = (sort {$a <=> $b} keys $HoH{'simpsons'})[0];
print $min;
```

Comment: What happens when you have `$HoH{simpsons}{10}`?

Comment: `sort` does more work than `min`, although for moderately sized hashes the difference probably isn't significant.